# Spring data available to the API client, but not at the runtime

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am implementing the Spring data jpa for the rest api project where I need to fetch the data from a table (with 5 sub-levels (child within in child)). The spring data jpa repository implementation with the query to the parent table is pulling the entities multiple level without any issues. I could see all the sub-levels of data in Postman for this rest api.

Issue is: when I try to access the value of child at the 4th level, it is empty. But, if I print in the console, the value is printed on the console. There is no value on the field or object during the debug time. For ex,

Parent

- Child 1

  - Child 2

    - Child 3

      - Child 4

        - Child 5

In the above example structure, the data from Parent to child 5 is retrieved and displayed in Postman, but is not available at the runtime.

The FetchType in all the tables are LAZY.

Comment: You couldn't see this information in debug mode because it didn't exist at that moment = hibernate didn't load this information. I guess. But you can still use expressions to evaluate data in debug mode. For example, in Intellij IDEA, the keyboard shortcut `ALT+F8` opens the evaluation window.